# Batch script to run Powershell script: Flashing window

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

System: Windows 10
Powershell Version: 5.1

Purpose: Run a powershell script from a batch file
Parameters: Directory, Filename, Server, Username, Password all being passed in as string encompassed in "" when called from command to handle the situation when there is a space (such as the Directory which currently has a space in)

The Powershell script works perfectly, it creates the credential and starts the RDP connection without issues. When calling from a batch file however the Powershell window flashes and closes immediately. Command Prompt window is run as Administrator.
I've tried using:
 - pause
 - -noexit
 - code from https://blog.danskingdom.com/allow-others-to-run-your-powershell-scripts-from-a-batch-file-they-will-love-you-for-it/

```
if ($Host.Name -eq "ConsoleHost")  
{  
    Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."  
    $Host.UI.RawUI.FlushInputBuffer()   # Make sure buffered input doesn't "press a key" and skip the ReadKey().  
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp") > $null  
}
```

- Clicking on the appearing Powershell window (To try get the select function to pause the window).
  None of which have worked.

The code in question is:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File """"%PowerShellScriptPath%"""" """"%server%"""" """"%username%"""" """"%password%""""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

Outside of this code no changes have been made to the system, the four speech marks were marked as required to pass through parameters and can be found under the blog post link above at the bottom just before the comments.
There is a high chance i'm using this incorrectly, I am a novice to batch and even newer to powershell. The batch scripts are being made as internal as possible, they need to be able to be used by a base install of Windows. They will eventually be migrated onto versions of Windows Server 2008 and up.

Is there anything that needs to be done with command prompt to allow it to run Powershell code?
Is the powershell code correct for the purpose i'm intending to use it for?
Is there any way, besides the ones listed, to view error, log information or pause the powershell window when run from a batch script?

Any input would be really appreciated!

**Edit:**
-NoExit variations:
**Parent Call**

```
PowerShell **-NoExit**  -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File """"%PowerShellScriptPath%"""" """"%server%"""" """"%username%"""" """"%password%""""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

**Nested call**

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '**-NoExit** -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File """"%PowerShellScriptPath%"""" """"%server%"""" """"%username%"""" """"%password%""""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

**Parent and Nested**

```
PowerShell **-NoExit**  -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '**-NoExit** -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File """"%PowerShellScriptPath%"""" """"%server%"""" """"%username%"""" """"%password%""""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

**Variables set inside batch script as:**

- SET server=%~1
  To remove the quotation marks I have also tried using:
- SET server=%1
  SET server=%server:"=%

Comment: I want to make sure I am reading this right. You have a cmd running and want to start Powershell  that Runs another Powershell that then Calls your script?
Honestly I feel like there is a better way to engineer this.
You said you are trying to open a RDP connection and it looks like you want users to access this by Commandline. Is this correct?

Comment: `PowerShell -NoProfile  -NoExit …`. Then you _could_ see an error? Please show a [mcve]: how do you set all used variables (obfuscating sensitive data).

Comment: Sorry if that came out a little confusing, my mind is in a bit of a knot.
The sequence for calling is: Batch script->Powershell Script->mstsc.exe
The project consists of multiple batch scripts which are called from a control file. That control file is passed parameters from another platform which are then handled by the control file and passed into the multiple batch files to perform processes.
If it would help I can detail the entire process I am currently trying to create in the main body?

Comment: `-NoExit` in batch script  (not inside script block). Maybe a percent sign or double quote in`%password%` could be harmful? Run using `ECHO ON` to see really performed command…

Comment: @JosefZ Having -NoExit in both the Parent and Nested call and turning on Echo has now allowed the Powershell window to stay open. Also from the echo I can see that it isn't passing the server and password parameter correctly.
I'll get onto those now, thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `SET "server=%~1"` (note  [position of double quotes which are not saved to variable](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)).